# Is there something better than the temporary table to be used in postgres to return a table (result) from the function?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I would like to know if there is some other "better" option to be used to return a result as a table from the pgsql function? Currently, the developer has used the temporary table to store the "temporary" data.

I'm looking at this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.fetch_data(a_panel_id bigint, a_hh_id bigint, a_site bigint, a_insert_date timestamp with time zone)
 RETURNS TABLE(panel_id bigint, hh_id bigint, site_id bigint, meter_raw_data text)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 ROWS 2000
AS $function$
DECLARE 
-- Stores each row returned from the table
rec record;
session_insert_time date;
session_id_v integer;

BEGIN
    create temp table interim_data (
    panel_id bigint,
    source_location_id bigint, 
    site_num bigint, 
    meter_data text
    ) on commit drop;

        FOR rec IN
            select rmd.primary_key as "id",
            rmd.source_location_id as "hh_id_tmp", 
            rmd.site_num as "site_tmp", 
            rmd.meterdata as "meter_data",
            rmd.panel_id as "panel_id_tmp"
            from checkout.rawmeterdata rmd 
            where 
            rmd.source_location_id = a_hh_id and 
            rmd.site_num = a_site and 
            rmd.panel_id = a_panel_id and
            rmd.is_polled=false and 
            rmd.insert_time > a_insert_date
            order by (rmd.insert_time) asc
        LOOP
            INSERT INTO interim_data 
            VALUES (
                    rec."panel_id_tmp",
                    rec."hh_id_tmp",
                    rec."site_tmp",
                    convert_from(rec."meter_data", 'UTF-8')
            );
        END LOOP;   
    return query select * from interim_data;
END $function$;
```

thank you

Comment: Why are you even doing a `LOOP` here? Just return the result of your query

Comment: Sure.. was looking and asking first.. It was strange also to me that a temporary table is used..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just return the result of the query. Does not even require PL/pgSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.fetch_data(a_panel_id bigint, a_hh_id bigint, a_site bigint, a_insert_date timestamp with time zone)
 RETURNS TABLE(panel_id bigint, hh_id bigint, site_id bigint, meter_raw_data text)
 LANGUAGE sql
 ROWS 2000
AS 
$function$
   select rmd.panel_id,
          rmd.source_location_id,
          rmd.site_num,
          convert_from(rmdmeterdata , 'UTF-8')
   from checkout.rawmeterdata rmd 
   where rmd.source_location_id = a_hh_id and 
         rmd.site_num = a_site and 
         rmd.panel_id = a_panel_id and
         rmd.is_polled=false and 
         rmd.insert_time > a_insert_date
   order by rmd.insert_time;
END 
$function$;
```